# Changing some text in the Fivestar module

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I'm using the Fivestar module in Drupal 6...
http://drupal.org/project/fivestar

And, I want to change the text:

From:  `Average: *****`

To This:  `Rate this Article: *****`

I'd rather not hack the module of use string overrides, I'm hoping to use a hook_form_alter function or something similar in the template.php file.

Here's is what the HTML looks like:

```
<form action="/fall-foliage"  accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" id="fivestar-form-node-232" class="fivestar-widget"><div>
<div class="fivestar-form-vote-232 clear-block"><input type="hidden" name="content_type" id="edit-content-type" value="node"  />
<input type="hidden" name="content_id" id="edit-content-id" value="232"  /><div class="fivestar-form-item  fivestar-average-stars fivestar-labels-hover">
<div class="form-item" id="edit-vote-wrapper">
<label for="edit-vote">Average: </label>
...etc...
```

Code in fivestar.module looks like this:

```
function theme_fivestar_summary($user_rating, $average_rating, $votes, $stars = 5, $feedback = TRUE) {
  $output = '';
  $div_class = '';
  if (isset($user_rating)) {
    $div_class = isset($votes) ? 'user-count' : 'user';
    $user_stars = round(($user_rating * $stars) / 100, 1);
    $output .= '<span class="user-rating">'. t('Your rating: <span>!stars</span>', array('!stars' => $user_rating ? $user_stars : t('None'))) .'</span>';
  }
  if (isset($user_rating) && isset($average_rating)) {
    $output .= ' ';
  }
  if (isset($average_rating)) {
    $div_class = isset($votes) ? 'average-count' : 'average';
    $average_stars = round(($average_rating * $stars) / 100, 1);
    $output .= '<span class="average-rating">'. t('Average: <span>!stars</span>', array('!stars' => $average_stars)) .'</span>';
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in fivestar.module file search for 'Average' not 'average' and can change as per your wise, But changing core module file is not recommend(Whenever you update your module, changes revert back).

Please create custom module and implement [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6)

Example:
function **YourModuleName**_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id)

Print $form and search for 'Average'

change $form[xyz][xyz] = 'Average' to $form[xyz][xyz] = 'Rate this Article'

if is not form, use [hook_nodeapi](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6)